# Data Binding using Mvvm Helpers

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind some data using MvvmHelpers by creating an object and binding that object.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers

In my model I have several data to bind so I just made a quick template of what I'm working on.

If I move what is inside NameModel to NameViewModel it does work however I'm trying separate my data.

Model:

```
public class NameModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
        }
    }
```

View Model:

```
public class NameViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        NameModel nameModel;

        public NameViewModel()
        {

            nameModel = new NameModel { name="Jon Doe" };
        }
    }
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class NamePage : ContentPage
    {
        public NamePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new NameViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="NameProj.NamePage">
    <StackLayout
        Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Text={Binding Name}/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing it to `nameModel.Name`?

```
<Label
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Text="{Binding nameModel.Name}"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer plus Alessandro Caliaro's makes it correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
NameModel nameModel;
```

I think should be public

```
public NameModel nameModel {get; set;}
```

and Yes, I think @mindOfAi is correct

Comment: haha of course! I figured that out right before I read your answered. I had to make it public to get access to it!

Comment: Yes, that too! Hahaha.